# Lotus Notes User with Editor Access can't delete documents (Option is activated in ACL)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, access-control

Currently I develop a database for another employee at my company. I have Manager Rights at the database to access everything. The administrator of the database should only be able to create/edit/delete documents. He currently got Editor-Access with selected "delete documents"-option. When he wants to delete a document on the database (i tried it with Simple Actions or with Javascript Code-both don't work) he gets redirected to the same page and nothing happens or with Simple Actions the Server-Login page shows up with the message "You don't have the permission to perform this action".

When im testing the functions with my manager access everything works fine. But when i'm changing my rank to Editor like the normal administrator of the database i also can't delete any documents. Like i already said the option in the ACL is activated.

I hope you can understand my problem and there is a solution for it. Normally that access right works fine on every other database at our company.

Another point: There are no Reader or Editor fields in the Documents. So there is no restriction with fields. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if there is some code in the QueryDocumentDelete event for the database.  Perhaps that is failing and / or preventing you from deleting.

Comment: I just checked the Code of it and there is not even something in it. We don't use this at another database anyway. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you mention redirecting and server login, I presume it's a web enabled database?

In which case have you tried looking at the ACL (Access Control List) for the problem database and clicking the Advanced tab.

In there is a field **Maximum Internet name and password**, this is the maximum access allowed for internet users.  If it's not editor, this could be the problem?

Comment: That's correct it's a web enabled database. I tried out your suggestion and at Maximum Internet name and passwort "Manager" is enabled. So everyone below should be also able to perform actions that are given.

Comment: Does the user have permission to run agents on the server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deleting with `?DeleteDocument` URL. That way it will for sure not try to do anything else.
2. Check the user's access level at server with `Database.getCurrentAccessLevel()` and `Database.queryAccessPrivileges(String name)`

Comment: Thanks for the information you gave me. The problem was solved yesterday. The document lock was enabled at the database which caused the deleting problems. Now everything works fine.

Comment: OK I thought about that but I'm getting "Document locking is enabled. You must lock the document before deleting." in that case. Maybe the way deletion is attempted affects the error message.

Comment: For example if I use `?DeleteDocument` as I advised in my answer I get the above error which tells that it needs to be locked. Now that you have solved it please write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the great suggestions of you all the problem was the checkbox "Allow document locking" at the database properties was enabled. That caused the problems at deleting documents. As Manager is have enough rights to go over that but for the normal Administrator with Editor Access the deletion request got blocked by the little option.

Thanks to everyone!